# How to use the Validator controls with controls other than TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, .net-3.5

I want to use the Validator control to validate a FCKEditor rich text control.  Is there a way to do this on either client and/or server side?

And a broader question, is there a way to use the Validator controls for anything other than text boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx(VS.71).aspx) control to perform custom validation logic. This control actually doesn't even require `ControlToValidate` to be set.

> It is possible to use a
>   CustomValidator control without
>   setting the ControlToValidate
>   property. This is commonly done when
>   you are validating multiple input
>   controls or validating input controls
>   that cannot be used with validation
>   controls, such as the CheckBox
>   control.

Comment: +1 and this allows for client-side validation as well. A tutorial can be found here: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx